# how to add numbers that are in an array so a highscore could be output

Tags: java

I need to find the sum of the ranks from 13 cards that a user is dealt.

this is in my class
card.java
which returns the value of the card as a string then the suit as a string and then the rank as an int.

```
public  String toString(){

String s = ("I am the " + rankString[rank-2] + " of " + suit + "(rank): " + rank);

    return  s;

}
```

this is in my CardFrame class.
CardFrame.java

```
private void doButton1Stuff(){
    //textArea.append("\nButton 1 Clicked");
    textArea.setText("");
    for(int i = 0; i<13; i++){
    textArea.append(deck.getNextCard().toString()+"\n");
    }
```

everything is working fine i just need to figure out a way to add all the ranks together from the 13 cards the user is dealt and output that as their score.

```
public Card getNextCard(){
    //check for end of deck
        topCard++;
        if(topCard==53){
        topCard = 1;
        shuffle();
        }


    return cards[deck[topCard-1]];
```

Comment: What object does deck.getNextCard() return? Does it have a rank getter? String parsing is far more cumbersome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need an accessor for your `rank` variable.

```
public int getRank() {
    return rank;
}
```

Then you can use it for every card in some collection (here I assume an array):

```
for(Card c: cards) {
    sum += c.getRank();
}
```

For your use case, it could be used here:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<13; i++) {
    Card c = deck.getNextCard();
    textArea.append(c.toString()+"\n");
    sum += c.getRank();
}
```

Comment: Why not just do the addition in the already used card loop which he uses to append to the text area?

Comment: Wherever is fine; I was merely showing how it could be invoked.

Comment: thank you i did have a getRank in my code, but not to sound like a complete noob but how would i append it to my textarea now i just want it underneath all the cards that are showing themselves

Comment: That sounds like a separate question to me.  I'm not 100% sure myself.

Answer (score 0):

In case you cant access to your rank value from Card class you can always read it from its `toString()` output like this:

```
String cardToStringOutput = "I am the " + "rankString[rank-2]" + " of "
        + "suit" + "(rank): " + "11";
int rank=Integer.parseInt(cardToStringOutput.split(" ")[6]);
System.out.println("rank="+rank);
```

But consider to add some getter to Card class so you don't have to do use above code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your "Card" class (I can't tell what you've named it from your code) has a "rank" member which I'm guess is an integer.  So I think what you're having trouble with is the iteration.  Try this:

```
private void doButton1Stuff(){
    //textArea.append("\nButton 1 Clicked");
    textArea.setText("");
    int score = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<13; i++){
        Card card = deck.getNextCard();
        score += card.rank
        textArea.append(card.toString()+"\n");
    }
    textArea.append("Score: ");
    textArea.append(score);
}
```

This assumes that your member var "rank" is accessible (see "public", "protected", "private")